# How to give margin top in datatable pagination?

Tags: css, datatable, datatables

I want to give a spacing showed in the pic in the yellow area like margin top  of the pagination (previous/next bars margin to horizontal scroll bar). is this possible using datatables variables or by using css ? If so how can i achieve that?

Below i am showing the php code and the javascript codes.

[image]

```
<div class="card border-light shadow-sm my-4">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table id="data-table" style="width:100%;"
                                class="table table-centered table-nowrap mb-0 rounded nowrap">
                                <thead class="thead-light">

                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="border-0">Sl No.</th>
                                        <th class="border-0">Apartment Name</th>
                                        <th class="border-0">Address (Short)</th>
                                        <th class="border-0">Address (Full)</th>
                                        <th class="border-0">Landmark</th>
                                        <th class="border-0">Pincode</th>
                                      
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>


                                    <?php 
                                    include '../../php/connection.php';

                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM info";
                                    $stmt=$dbcon->prepare($query);
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
                                    $datas=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                    foreach ($datas as $key => $data)
                                    {
                            ?>
                                    <!-- Item -->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="border-0">
                                            <?php echo $key+1 ; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="border-0">
                                            <?php echo $data['apartment_name']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="border-0">
                                            <?php echo $data['addr_short']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="border-0">
                                            <?php echo $data['addr_full']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="border-0">
                                            <?php echo $data['landmark']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="border-0">
                                            <?php echo $data['pincode']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        

                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- End of Item -->

                                    <?php      
                                }
                            ?>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

js code-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
        "scrollX": true
    });
});
</script>
```

-Thank you

Comment: you should provide your code so we can help you.

Comment: @mkafiyan ok i am giving my code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move the pagination controls down slightly, you can use the DataTables [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option to place the controls in a custom `<div>`. You can give that `<div>` a class name, and then attach a style to it.

The default `dom` value is:

```
"dom": 'lfrtip'
```

Each letter refers to a control (e.g. `t` is the table itself; `p` is the pagination).

We can change that default to this:

```
"dom": 'lfrti<"bottom-wrapper"p>'
```

This wraps the `p` in a div.

The div can then be styled however you wish - for example:

```
<style>
  .bottom-wrapper {
      margin-top: 0.5em;
  }
</style>
```

If you want both the info and pagination controls to be adjusted, then put the `i` inside the div also:

```
"dom": 'lfrt<"bottom-wrapper"ip>'
```

---

**Update** for the search box comment:

Looking at the [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) documentation, the search box is represented by the letter `f` (for filtering input).

So, you put that in a `<div>` and give it its own class name:

```
"dom": 'l<"top-wrapper"f>rti<"bottom-wrapper"p>'
```

Now the letter `f` is wrapped: `<"top-wrapper"f>`

I suppose you want to move that up slightly, so, a style could be:

```
.top-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: i tried as you said. The "show 10/25/50 entries " menu ,pagination bar goes down but the "search box "is still at same position as before. So what can i do to move the search box too like others a little bit?

Comment: I don't know where your search box is. But assuming it is above your table, and assuming you want to move it up slightly, I have added a note to my answer. It's basically the same approach as for the pagination.

Comment: Yes it was on the top right. And your ans was correct. Thank you .